# Get list of all magento stores which have same locale

Tags: php, magento

How can I get list of all **Magento** stores on phtml file, which have same locale

Comment: @MahmoodRehman If there is 5 stores on website and 2 stores have en_US language and other have fr_FR language. then How can I get store id which have en_US language selected.

Comment: I think you can get stores on website bases not on languages basis.Each store have separate view depends on language/view.You should fetch all stores on website base , then filter what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no direct query for get this type of requirement.But ,i have found an alternative solution.Here is below

```
$Stores=array();
 $storeCollection=Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection();
 foreach($storeCollection as $store)
 {

    $storelang= Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $store->getId());
     if(!isset($Stores[$storelang])){
            $Stores[$storelang]=array();
            $Stores[$storelang]['store']=array();


         }
         $Stores[$storelang]['lang']=$storelang;
         $Stores[$storelang]['store'][]=$store->getData();
     }
     foreach($Stores as $eachstore)
     {
      echo '<pre>';
     print_r($eachstore);
     echo '<pre>';
     }
```

Let me know if you have any issue

Comment: thank you! (but the indentation is not super pretty.. sorry)